# How to display the store name and logo with Twig?

Tags: drupal-8

I customize the display of my product with a twig template.

How to display the store name and logo with Twig ?

For the name, there are no fields.

For the image the field in store type is `field_professionnel_logo`

The code below works, but it does not display the name and the box of the store.

```
<article{{ attributes }}>

    <h3 class="views-teaser-title">
      {{ product.title }}
    </h3>

    <div class="views-teaser-variation">
      {{ product.variation_price }}
      {{ product.variations }}
    </div>

    <div class="views-teaser-relation-name">
      <div class="views-teaser-relation-store-image">
        {{ product.store_field_professionnel_logo }}
      </div> 
      <div class="views-teaser-relation-store-name">
        Ce produit est proposé par la boutique {{ product.store_title }}
      </div>
    </div>

</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the **name** (which I hypothetically think is the **title** field) you should just use the `.value`.

```
<h3 class="views-teaser-title">
  {{ product.title.value }}
</h3>
```

Regarding the logo, if it's an *image field*, the following code will work:

```
<img src="{{ product.store_field_professionnel_logo.entity.uri.value }}">
```

I hope I help you to resolve your issue.